# Screeps: store reference to source in creeps memory?

Tags: javascript, screeps

Fascinating game!

Looking for an example of how to persist a reference to a particular energy source in a creep's memory. Seems that storing the actual source object won't work(?).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't store object instances, but you can store their IDs.

```
if(!creep.memory.targetSourceId) {
    var source = creep.pos.findNearest(Game.SOURCES_ACTIVE);
    creep.memory.targetSourceId = source.id;
}
```

And then you can use [`Game.getObjectById()`](http://screeps.com/docs/Game.php#getObjectById) to find this particular source.

```
var source = Game.getObjectById(creep.memory.targetSourceId);
creep.moveTo(source);
```

Comment: In the latest version you can use Game.getObjectById(), rather than filtering.